# When I make the configure of ctags-5.8 has the undeclared identifie Erro

Tags: gcc, ctags

On Mac 10.15
When i make the configure of ctags-5.8, I have the problem:

```
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c main.c

In file included from main.c:62:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h:80:2: error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'unused'
    __unused long   __padding; /* (__dd_rewind space left for bincompat) */
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:161:40: note:
  expanded from macro '__unused'
#define __unused        __attribute__((__unused__))
                                   ^
./general.h:60:37: note: expanded from macro '__unused__'
# define __unused__  __attribute__((unused))
                                ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

#### gcc -v :

```
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 8.3.0_2)
```

Comment: That's a nasty bug and it's totally ctags fault - it shouldn't define a macro starting with double underscore. [this commit](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/commit/64ae08e5512f0e197e42dfefa724752e7a2c2f97) looks like it tries to do something with it but I doubt it succeedes. You think you should make an issue on ctags page and for now, try just removing `__attribute__((unused))` part leaving just empty `# define __unused__ ` or just remove the whole line from `general.h`.

Comment: yeal, I have no idea to deal with the issue.

Comment: Try just removing `__attribute__((unused))` from `./general.h` file from the line `# define __unused__  __attribute__((unused))` and leave just `# define __unused__`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in ctest. Identifiers starting with double `_` are reserved and are used by standard libraries. User program should not use such identifiers, because bugs like this can occur.